# Алгоритм проверки прямой видимости в 3d сцене

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Есть набор полигонов (треугольников) и координаты двух точек в пространстве (на 3d сцене). Нужно проверить, видно ли из одной точки другую.

Интересует, в первую очередь, в какой структуре хранить треугольники, чтобы проверка была быстрой. Я думал в сторону квадратичных деревьев, но есть сомнения: если треугольники большие, они все окажутся на верхнем уровне дерева.

Как можно оптимизировать наивный алгоритм, проверяющий каждый треугольник?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Октодерево в помощь.

С большими треугольниками ничего не поделать, обрабатывать в общем порядке. Но ведь их и не много?